# Edgeworth Box for exchange economy

Tags: microeconomics, pure-exchange-economy, edgeworth-box

Could you please tell me, if the Edgeworth Box I have drawn for the exchange economy is correct?
My professor's solution is really unclear.
Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite. The line you have drawn turns out to be the contract curve, but from this figure it's not clear how you get this line, because the indifference curves for the two utility functions are missing.

Moreover, Kevin's utility function should be $K_K^2 B_K$ instead of $K^2B$, and the sum of bread endowments is $90$, not $60$.

Comment: Thank you, but is the contract curve right? Thats all I need.

Comment: @AlinaJabs Yes, it's right.